# Node js - Number Of Processes 100 / 100 (100%) - cPanel shared hosting

Tags: shared-hosting

I am using linux shared hosting. I can't access the terminal. It shows `cagefs_enter: Unable to fork`. When I click "Setup Node.js App" it shows `The received data is wrong. Contact support for resolution. cagefs_enter: Unable to fork`.

Using a cron job, how can I terminate all unused nodejs processes after an hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pkill -15 node`. Which will terminate the node processes.

You may also use `pkill -9 node` or `killall node` but these are extreme.